# How to access IE XHTML DOM+JS engines without starting the browser itself

Tags: c#, javascript, internet-explorer

I'm trying to build a headless browser in c#. c# has plenty of classes, which are supposed to make this possible, like, for example JScriptCodeProvider.

I am looking to get IE XML DOM classes for the JavaScript code to work with. Can anyone tell me where to find those, and, if possible, to provide me with a workable example for what I'm trying do to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [webbrowser control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx).  That should get you everything you need.